# Select count for each specific date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have the following need:
I need to count the number of times each id activated from all dates.

Let's say the table looks like this:

```
tbl_activates
PersonId int,
ActivatedDate datetime
```

The result set should look something like this:

```
counted_activation | ActivatedDate
5             | 2009-04-30
7             | 2009-04-29
5             | 2009-04-28
7             | 2009-04-27
```

... and so on

Anyone know how to do this the best possible way? The date comes in the following format '2011-09-06 15:47:52.110', I need to relate only to the date without the time. (summary for each date)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: which datatype is the column ActivatedDate ?

Comment: datatype datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use count(distinct  .. )

and if the ActivatedDate is datetime you can get the date part

```
  select  Cast(ActivatedDate AS date), count(distinct id)
  from my_table 
  group by  ast(ActivatedDate AS date)
```

Comment: The `date()`-function is not available in all RDBMS. In PostgreSQL, MySQL and sql-server you can do `cast(ActivatedDate AS date)` instead.

Comment: @cars10m   correct ..(I had seemed to see the mysql tag)   answer update with proper cast

Answer (score 0):

You can use to_char function to remove the time from date

```
    select count(*) counted_activation, 
to_char(activatedDate,"yyyy-mm-dd") ActDate
    from table1
    group by to_char(activatedDate,"yyyy-mm-dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'GROUP BY' and 'COUNT'. Use CONVERT method to convert datetime to Date only

```
  SELECT CONVERT(DATE,activatedate), COUNT(userId)
  FROM [table]
  GROUP BY  CONVERT(DATE,InvoiceDate)
```